# Can setDisplayShowTitleEnabled be set in xml to theme an ActionBar?

Tags: android

I am trying to theme an `ActionBar` in xml rather than code. So far I have this:

```
<style name="TestTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/TestActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="TestActionBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
</style>
```

This is giving me my custom background and I want to be able to turn off the title here as well. In code, I would set `setDisplayShowTitleEnabled` to false. How do I do it in xml?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

ok, here is the answer. Adding this to the second style block above hid the titles.

```
<item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item>
```

Comment: but for showing the title, should use the "showTitle" value